# Installing imagick on MacOs Catalina - 'php.h' file not found

Tags: php, imagick

I tried installing imagick on my mac 10.15 Catalina and I get this:

```
/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/php_imagick.h:42:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [imagick_file.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Can someone help me out with a solution?

Comment: Looks like you need to have a PHP installed. Have you tried to install imagick with PHP extension?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I had PHP installed but a different version from a different stack and it was pointing to the wrong folder.